# Как выполнить <script> только на смартфоне?

Tags: javascript

Как выполнить  только на смартфоне? Например, подобный?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(w, n) {
        w[n] = w[n] || [];
        w[n].push(function() {
            Ya.Context.AdvManager.render({
                blockId: "R-A-123456-78",
                renderTo: "yandex_rtb_R-A-123456-78",
                async: false
            });
        });
        document.write('<sc'+'ript type="text/javascript" src="//an.yandex.ru/system/context.js"></sc'+'ript>');
    })(this, "yandexContextSyncCallbacks");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью такой проверки:

```js
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    alert("Вы используете мобильное устройство (телефон или планшет).")
} else alert("Вы используете ПК.")
```

Вот так:

```js
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  (function(w, n) {
    w[n] = w[n] || [];
    w[n].push(function() {
      Ya.Context.AdvManager.render({
        blockId: "R-A-123456-78",
        renderTo: "yandex_rtb_R-A-123456-78",
        async: false
      });
    });
    document.write('<sc' + 'ript type="text/javascript" src="//an.yandex.ru/system/context.js"></sc' + 'ript>');
  })(this, "yandexContextSyncCallbacks");
} else alert("Вы используете ПК.")
```

Вот, как можно создать, так сказать, декоратор, проверяющий на мобильное устройство:

```js
function mobileOnlyDecorator(cb, ...args) {
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    return cb(...args)
  }

  console.log("Это компьютер");
}

mobileOnlyDecorator((name, hello) => {
  console.log(`${hello}, ${name}`);
}, "Дорогой Друг", "Привет");
```

[Источник](https://only-to-top.ru/blog/coding/2019-11-16-opredelit-mobilnoe-ustrojstvo-javascript.html).

Answer (score 1):

Этот код добавит глобальную булевую переменную `isMobile` и добавит класс `mobile` в `<body>`

```js
(function(a) {
  const devRx1 = /android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|ad|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i;
  const devRx2 = /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i;
  if(window.isMobile = devRx1.test(a) || devRx2.test(a.substr(0, 4))){
    document.body.classList.add('mobile');
  }
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я предложу простой способ определить, что устройство именно смартфон. У смартфона ширина экрана всегда меньше высоты.

```
  wScreen = $(window).width(); hScreen = $(window).height();
// или на чистом JS
//screen.width  // Ширина экрана
//screen.height // Высота экрана
           if (wScreen < hScreen) {
              smartfon = true;// это смартфон.
              }
```

Comment: а если повернуть мобилу ?:)

Comment: У планшетов и вертикальных мониторов тоже ширина меньше высоты. А ещё когда браузер на десктопе сужен по ширине.

Comment: если повернуть смартфон  и в этом положении открыть сайт, то не определит что смартфон. Данный способ можно применять когда нужно , чтобы отображение приспосабливалось к соотношению ширины и высоты экрана устройства.

Comment: а я работаю за вертикальным монитором =) даж двумя =)

Comment: Данный способ 100% точно не определит смартфон это или нет. Но большинство предпочитает держать смартфон вертикально, планшет горизонтально и использовать горизонтальные мониторы. Предложенные в других ответах проверка на основе определения операционной системы , на мой взгляд тоже не является абсолютно точной, т.к не определит смартфон это или планшет и нуждается в своевременной корректировки в связи с появлением новых мобильных OC например Harmony OS от Huawei и Chrome OS от Google – YuriCoder 12 минут назад